# Authorize Jenkins to list pods in its own K8S namespace

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins

So I am deploying a Jenkins instance inside my K8S cluster using Helm.

Here is the flow that I am following :

1) Create Namespace called `jenkins-pipeline`.

```
kubectl get ns jenkins-pipeline -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-09-15T16:58:33Z
  name: jenkins-pipeline
  resourceVersion: "25596"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/jenkins-pipeline
  uid: 9449b9e7-b908-11e8-a915-080027bfdbf9
spec:
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes
status:
  phase: Active
```

2) Create ServiceAccount called `jenkins-admin` INSIDE namespace `jenkins-pipeline`.

```
kubectl get serviceaccounts -n jenkins-pipeline jenkins-admin -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-09-15T17:02:25Z
  name: jenkins-admin
  namespace: jenkins-pipeline
  resourceVersion: "25886"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/jenkins-pipeline/serviceaccounts/jenkins-admin
  uid: 1e921d43-b909-11e8-a915-080027bfdbf9
secrets:
- name: jenkins-admin-token-bhvdd
```

3) Create ClusterRoleBinding linking my ServiceAccount `jenkins-admin` to ClusterRole `cluster-admin`. (I know this is not best practise to assign my deployment that much privilege but Im just testing for now locally).

```
kubectl get clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io jenkins-cluster-role-binding -o yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-09-15T16:58:33Z
  name: jenkins-cluster-role-binding
  resourceVersion: "25597"
  selfLink: /apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterrolebindings/jenkins-cluster-role-binding
  uid: 944a4c18-b908-11e8-a915-080027bfdbf9
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: jenkins-admin
  namespace: jenkins-pipeline
```

4) Deploy my pod in namespace `jenkins-pipeline`.

5) Expose deployment using service in namespace `jenkins-pipeline`.

Jenkins comes up perfectly fine but when I try to test my Kuberenetes connection, it fails stating :

```
Error testing connection https://192.168.99.100:8443: Failure executing: GET at: https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/namespaces/jenkins-pipeline/pods. Message: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may have been revoked. pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:jenkins-pipeline:default" cannot list pods in the namespace "jenkins-pipeline".
```

A snippet of the UI looks like :

[image]

Ive configured this to the best of my knowledge. I created the serviceaccount in the namespace and gave this serviceaccount SUPER privileges. And yet it cannot list pods in its own namespace. Any help will be appreciated.

I tried to change namespace in the Jenkins UI but I have a feeling it defaults to `jenkins-pipeline` even if I dont state it.

Comment: Do you have the pod configured to use the service account?

Comment: Looks like you are spot on. I added `serviceAccount: {{ .Values.serviceaccount.name }}` to my helm deployment.yaml template file and now all is good !

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to David Maze's indication, I got it figured out. I was missing a crucial piece which was to make my deployment use the newly created ServiceAccount.

Needed to add it to the deployment file under spec.template.spec :

```
  spec:
    containers:
    - env:
      - name: JAVA_OPTS
        value: -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false
      image: jeunii/my-jenkins-base:1.0
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    .
    .
    serviceAccount: jenkins-admin
    .
    .
```